# C# WCF Error on change Endpoint

Tags: c#, web-services, wcf

I'm doing a service to comunicate only for test and learning, 
but I'm trying to change the URL Endpoint and its returning a error

```
n: There was no endpoint listening at http://servername:8732/TestService/ that could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action.
```

That is my code:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

            var myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
            myBinding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.None;
            var myEndPointAdress = new EndpointAddress("http://servername:8732/TestService/");
            MyCalculatorServiceClient service = new MyCalculatorServiceClient(myBinding, myEndPointAdress);

            MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(service.soma(Convert.ToInt32(textBox1.Text), Convert.ToInt32(textBox2.Text))));

    }
```

App.config "Edited":

```
           <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
    <startup> 
        <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5.2" />
        </startup>
        <system.serviceModel>
            <bindings>
                <basicHttpBinding>
                    <binding name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCalculatorService" />
                </basicHttpBinding>
            </bindings>
            <client>
              <endpoint address="http://servername:8732/TestService/"
                  binding="basicHttpBinding" bindingConfiguration="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCalculatorService"
                  contract="ServiceReference1.IMyCalculatorService" name="BasicHttpBinding_IMyCalculatorService">
                <identity>
                  <dns value="localhost" />
                </identity>
              </endpoint>
            </client>
        </system.serviceModel>
    </configuration>
```

Comment: The error is pretty clear.  Are you able to browse to the service URL and get the service page?   Is this self-hosted?   Is the service running when you try to connect to it?

Comment: Hum it sets to the initial URL in the service. For this adress http: // localhost: 57763 / MyCalculatorService.svc

Comment: Can you post the full system.servicemodel section from your config

Comment: You are only showing the client configuration. Did you change the service URL too?